# MySQL To Mongodb query issue

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I want to thank everyone who has helped me in the past as well as your time to read this post.

I have an issue with converting my sql query to mongodb query.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT m_time,m_latency FROM pkt_tbl WHERE (m_time-m_latency+" . LATENCY_DELTA . ")>=" . $rangeXFrom . " AND (m_time-m_latency+" . LATENCY_DELTA . ")<=" . $rangeXTo . " ORDER BY (m_time-m_latency+" . LATENCY_DELTA . ")"
```

**Mongodb Query (My Try)**

```
$latency_delta_split = array('m_time-m_latency'=>LATENCY_DELTA);
$find_query = array($latency_delta_split=>array('$gte'=>$rangeXFrom),$latency_delta_split=>array('$lte'=>$rangeXTo));
$find_projectins = array('m_time'=>1, 'm_latency'=>1);    $find_query = array(('m_time-m_latency'=>LATENCY_DELTA)=>array('$gte'=>$rangeXFrom),('m_time-m_latency'=>LATENCY_DELTA)=>array('$lte'=>$rangeXTo));
```

I am still getting an error and couldn't really figure out the solution.

**What I have done:**

```
1] Read Mongodb Docs.
2] Searched on StackOverflow for similar problems. (None addressed mine)
3] Refered to PHP.NET official docs.
```

However, I couldn't figure out, Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the query does not run. And I am pretty much sure there's an error in the query. (I did not do the ORDER BY yet but the query which I have written has errors in it that's for sure. If someone can help me point out that would be great.

Comment: Yes, but what SPECIFIC error are you getting. When you call Mondo and you get no results, are you looking at what error you are getting (i.e. something more specific than "it doesn't work")?

Comment: It says the following `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - syntax error, unexpected ','
 - syntax error, unexpected 
  '=>'`

But I am pretty sure that my the syntax i wrote is incorrect. Can you please correct my syntax.

Comment: can you clear what LATENCY_DELTA

Comment: Didn't I answer anohter one of your questions that contained similar errors? If you had referred to the PHP docs you would know your array syntax is wrong which makes me think you have not

Comment: @Sammaye I did refer to the manual, i realized that my syntax was wrong. However, even if i tried to correct my syntax I am unable to understand how do i do (-) operation in the query. Or Where I am going wrong. I could modify the question with the updated query that i have done but still that does not solve my issue(Moreover I don't think it's good to change the question so)

Comment: @NanheKumar It's a global variable (if that's what they call it in PHP). lets assume it's something like 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your SQL you have: `m_time-m_latency` which I presume means subtract one column from another.

*The short answer:*

This is not something you can represent with MongoDB queries yet as you can only compare fields with static values.

*The long answer:*

If you want to find documents where `m_time - m_latency + LATENCY_DELTA` is in a specific range then you will have to store that value **pre-calculated** in another field of the document. If you do that, then you can simply run the query with:

```
db.collection.find( { 'm_calculated_latency' : { '$gte' : FROM_RANGE, '$lte' : TO_RANGE } } );
```

Or in PHP:

```
$collection->find( array(
    'm_calculated_latency' => array(
        '$gte' => $from_range,
        '$lte' => $to_range,
    )
)
```

*The workaround:*

With MongoDB's aggregation framework, you can probably do a query like you want, but it will by far not be the fastest or most elegant solution and neither does it use an index. So **please** redesign your schema and add that pre-calculated field.

With the warning out of the way, here goes:

```
FROM=3
TO=5
DELTA=1
db.so.aggregate( [ 
    { $project: { 
        'time': { $add: [
            { $subtract: [ '$m_time', '$m_latency' ] },
            DELTA
        ] },
        'm_time' : 1,
        'm_latency' : 1
    } }, 
    { $match: { 'time' : { $gte: FROM, $lte: TO } } },
    { $sort: { 'time' : 1 } }
] );
```

In the *$project* step, we're calculating the field time as `m_time - m_latency + DELTA`. We also output the original `m_time` and `m_latency` fields. And then in the *$match* step, we are comparing the calculated `time` with either `FROM` or `TO`. And lastly we sort by the calculated `time`. (As your original SQL sort didn't make sense either, I assumed you meant to sort by the time difference).

With my input data:

```
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 5, m_latency: 3 } );
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 5, m_latency: 1 } );
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 8, m_latency: 1 } );
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 8, m_latency: 3 } );
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 7, m_latency: 2 } );
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 7, m_latency: 4 } );
> db.so.insert( { m_time: 7, m_latency: 6 } );
> FROM=3
> TO=5
> DELTA=1
```

This produces:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51e7988af4f32a33dac184e8"),
            "m_time" : 5,
            "m_latency" : 3,
            "time" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51e7989af4f32a33dac184ed"),
            "m_time" : 7,
            "m_latency" : 4,
            "time" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51e7988cf4f32a33dac184e9"),
            "m_time" : 5,
            "m_latency" : 1,
            "time" : 5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now the last trick is to write the aggregate query from above in PHP syntax, which as you can see is quite trivial:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient;
$db = $m->test;

$r = $db->so->aggregate( [ 
    [ '$project' =>  [
        'time' => [ '$add' => [
            [ '$subtract' => [ '$m_time', '$m_latency' ] ],
            $DELTA
        ] ],
        'm_time' => 1,
        'm_latency' => 1
    ] ], 
    [ '$match' => [ 'time' => [ '$gte' => $FROM, '$lte' => $TO ] ] ],
    [ '$sort' => [ 'time' => 1 ] ]
] );
var_dump( $r );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. You can't chain together `=>` when specifying key value pairs in cases like this:

```
('m_time-m_latency'=>LATENCY_DELTA)=>array('$gte'=>$rangeXFrom)
```

I honestly am not sure what you are trying to do there so as to give better advice.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a SQL query, I am trying to write a mongodb query for that. I have written few simple one's but this one looks complicated. Don't know how to tackle that.